# DebounceTime for api call and form reset Angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to have a reset button for my search but as well as the debounce.  This is what I currently have.  I believe my issue is that I am losing the 'this' for the form once I reset.

```
searchForm = new FormControl('');

constructor(private searchService: SearchService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.getSearch();
  });
}

getSearch(){
    this.searchService.getSearch(this.searchForm.value).subscribe( res => console.log(res);
}

onReset(){
    this.searchForm.reset();
}
```

I am brand spanking new to Angular and I am sure this is terrible, I appreciate the help.

Comment: added answer below.

Comment: So what you're looking for is to have `reset events` going through the same _pipeline_ from `valueChanges`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your reset Event to :-

```
onReset(){
    this.searchForm.reset(null, {emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true});
}
```

This will prevent to emit this change to your valueChanges and no impact on your debounce time or so.

Comment: Still isn't working for me.  I had to change it to, this.seachSubscription in ngOnInit, but same issue when I reset the form it doesn't pick up the new changes.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: what behaviour do you expect?

Comment: This one might be more clear, I changed the console.log to an alert. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n6mn2t  After the reset button is hit I would still expect the alert to come through but it doesn't appear to fire.

Comment: updated my solution above. please discard changes i suggested earlier. use the solution from above.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you so much!